Add online maps to my maps
I have started a map by myself and added layers. While reaserching, I found a website with several small maps of the country which I would like to add to my map. Do I have to download the files, one for each map, and import them to my map? Is there a way to simply copy+paste without downloading?

Are the "small maps of the country" you want to add static "images" of maps, or are they embedded maps from Google Maps (or similar)?
